# How to check whether there is a real root of $f(x)$ in $(0 \:\: 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

Given $f : \mathbb{R} \to (0 \: \: 1)$ a continous function. Then which of the following has a real root in $(0 \:\: 1)$

The functions that are given are

$1.$ $$g(x)=e^x -\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \sin t dt$$

For this i have chosen $f(x)$ as $|\sin x|$ since its domain is $R$ and range is $(0 \:\: 1)$

Then we get

$$g(x)= e^x -\int_{0}^{x} |\sin x| \sin xdx=e^x-\int_{0}^{x}\sin^2x dx=e^x-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\frac{\sin2x}{2}\right)$$

Now $$g(0)=1$$

and $$g(1)=e-0.5+\frac{\sin 2}{4} \gt 0$$

Hence there is no real toot of $g(x)=0$ in $(0 \:\: 1)$.

Any other way to find this?

Comment: By the way, $|\sin x|\sin x\neq\sin^2 x$ all the time - eg see $x=-3\pi/2$. This is only true if $\sin x\geq0$.

Comment: Also, let $h(x)=(x-\frac12)^2-\frac12$ on $(0,1)$. $h(0)=h(1)=-\frac14$, ie both are less than $0$ but this doesn't necessarily mean there are no roots of $h(x)$ in this region, just that if there are roots, then there are an even number of them (including multiplicity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any continuous $f:\mathbb R\to (0,1)$ and any $t\in \mathbb R$ we have $|f(t)\sin t|\leq |\sin t|\leq 1$.   So for $x>0$ we have $$|\int_0^xf(t)\sin t \;dt|\leq \int_0^x |f(t)\sin t|\;dt \leq \int_0^x|\sin t|\;dt\leq \int_0^x 1 \;dt =x<e^x$$ so $x\in (0,1)\implies x>0\implies g(x)>0$.